# Table join including rows that do not have an entry - SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, aggregate-functions

I'm having a little bit of difficulty joining two tables together, involving a SUM which are not included in the second table.

I.e. I have two tables:

#### tblClient

```
 ID|FirstName|LastName
 1 |Billy    |Blogs
 2 |Bobby    |Biggs
 3 |Hill     |Bill
 4 |Super    |Man
```

#### tblComplete

```
 PurchaseID|ID|Amount
 123123    |1 |26.00
 43254     |2 |22.00
 546275    |3 |15.00
 463565    |3 |15.00
 343252    |1 |56.00
```

What I would like to do is join these two tables together, so that I get an output of:

```
 ID|FirstName|LastName| SUM(Amount)
 1 |Billy    |Blogs   | 82.00
 2 |Bobby    |Biggs   | 22.00
 3 |Hill     |Bill    | 30.00
 4 |Super    |Man     | 0
```

I would like Super Man to be included in the output, with a sum of zero, because he didn't purchase anything.  How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: Primary key in tblComplete table.

Answer (score 6):

```
select
  CL.ID,
  CL.FirstName,
  CL.LastName,
  coalesce(CO.SumAmount, 0) as [SUM(Amount)]
from tblClient as CL
  left outer join
    (
      select
        sum(Amount) as SumAmount,
        ID
      from tblComplete
      group by ID
    ) as CO
    on CL.ID = CO.ID
```

Comment: +1 for putting the coalesce outside the sum() calculations, and for quoting things likely to be taken as keywords...

Answer (score 3):

**SQL Server:**

You start your statement with a select from tblClient, which contains one record for each record in your output. Then you [LEFT JOIN](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7115.asp), you perform a grouping on ClientID and utilize the aggregate function SUM() that causes each client's amount(s) (if they exist at all) to be summed up.

```
SELECT
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName, 
  Sum(ISNULL(COMP.Amount, 0)) as Sum 
FROM 
  tblClient as CLIENT 
  LEFT JOIN tblComplete as COMP on COMP.ID = CLIENT.ID 
GROUP BY 
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.ID,a.FirstName,a.LastName, sum(b.Amount)  from tblClient a , tblComplete b where a.ID = b.ID group by b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, use an OUTER JOIN, or LEFT JOIN (since LEFT JOINS are outer to begin with..)

See more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins

The keyword outer makes is include rows even if they don't have a record in both tables. LEFT or RIGHT is really just which side of the `=` the null-able table is on.

Answer (score 1):

Try whit LEFT JOIN ?

```
SELECT
    tblClient.*,
    SUM(tblComplete.amount) as Amount
FROM
    tblClient
LEFT JOIN
    tblComplete ON tblClient.ID = tblComplete.ID
GROUP BY
    tblClient.id
```

If this no work (i don't execute it), try:

```
SELECT
    tblClient.*,
    IF(COUNT(tblComplete.*), SUM(tblComplete.amount), 0) as Amount
FROM
    tblClient
LEFT JOIN
    tblComplete ON tblClient.ID = tblComplete.ID
GROUP BY
    tblClient.id
```

Answer (score 1):

[Using Aggregate Functions in the Select List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213243%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
SELECT
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName, 
  Sum(ISNULL(COMP.Amount, 0)) as Sum
FROM 
  tblClient as CLIENT 
  LEFT JOIN tblComplete as COMP on COMP.ID = CLIENT.ID 
GROUP BY 
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName
```

OR

```
SELECT
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName, 
  Sum(ISNULL(COMP.Amount, 0)) as Sum 
FROM 
  tblClient as CLIENT 
  Inner JOIN tblComplete as COMP on COMP.ID = CLIENT.ID 
GROUP BY 
  CLIENT.ID, 
  CLIENT.FirstName, 
  CLIENT.LastName
```